# Python: How to make object attribute refer call a method

Tags: python, attributes

I'd like for an attribute call like `object.x` to return the results of some method, say `object.other.other_method()`. How can I do this?

Edit: I asked a bit soon: it looks like I can do this with

```
object.__dict__['x']=object.other.other_method()
```

Is this an OK way to do this?

Comment: Re: your edit — Yes and no… your solution will *store* the results of `object.other.other_method()` in `object.x`, which means that the method will only be called once, not each time `object.x` is read.  If you want the method to be called every time, @muksie has it right — check out the `property` decorator.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the property decorator

```
class Test(object): # make sure you inherit from object
    @property
    def x(self):
        return 4

p = Test()
p.x # returns 4
```

Mucking with the __dict__ is dirty, especially when @property is available.

Comment: Is there a way to do that dynamically?

Comment: The example given doesn't solve the "set property" scenario.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the built-in [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) function.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `property`

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        print "in get_x: do something here"
        return self._x

    def set_x(self, x):
        print "in set_x: do something"
        self._x = x

    x = property(get_x, set_x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MyClass(10)
    # getting x
    print 'm.x is %s' % m.x
    # setting x
    m.x = 5
    # getting new x
    print 'm.x is %s' % m.x
```

Answer (score 4):

This will only call `other_method` once when it is created

```
object.__dict__['x']=object.other.other_method()
```

Instead you could do this

```
object.x = property(object.other.other_method)
```

Which calls `other_method` everytime `object.x` is accessed

Of course you aren't really using `object` as a variable name, are you?

Comment: When using this option `object.x = property(object.other.other_method)`, I get `<property at 0x1941f02cf48>` when accessing the `x` attribute, what should I do differently?